# vscode "applying code action organize Imports"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently got an annoying issue with VS and saving ts files.

every time I save a ts file I get a little popup in the bottom right telling me its "applying code action organize Imports".

I've tried uninstalled VSCode, removing all extensions, deleting the code folder in Roaming. As far as I can tell all my user settings are blank and it should be back to a clean install of VSCode. I've tried looking in the settings for something similar, even adding this to my settings.

```
{
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": false
}
```

}

However, I'm still getting the same message on save and its restructuring the imports.

I've got vs code installed on another 2 machines and don't get the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: It takes so looong to organize imports, is there anything wrong with my vscode?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the folder I was opening had its own custom .vscode folder with its own settings.json which had the organizeImports setting enabled. So no matter what I did to my local settings file this one was always overriding it and nothing was showing up within VS directly.

Comment: I was losing my mind trying to figure this out today....

Answer (score 3):

I had forgotten to select a Python interpreter in vscode. Once I did this, the pop up on bottom right telling saying its "applying code action organize Imports" stopped appearing. This solved it for me.

Comment: This was my issue too! Thank you, worked charmingly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, **I switched the Typescript version to the workspace version** and that fixed my issue